# Assign one or another subclass to a single variable in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to use a single variable to call subclass methods with, but I have two different subclasses the variable might be. I have a superclass Student and subclasses Grad and UnderGrad. The methods for both subclasses are called the same, just implemented differently. Basically, I want something like this that works:

```
if (studentType == 1) {
    UnderGrad student = new UnderGrad();
} else {
    Grad student = new Grad();
}

student.setNumAssignments();
student.setNumDiscussions();
student.setNumMidweekAssignments();
```

Comment: You need a superclass or interface to represent that variable. Something like a `Student` parent class. Then the instances are just your subclass versions.

Comment: `Student student = studentType == 1 ?  new UnderGrad() : new Grad();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare the variable of a common ancestor, then conditionally assign to it:

```
Student student;

if (studentType == 1) {
    student = new UnderGrad();
} else {
    student = new Grad();
}

student.setNumAssignments();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had initialized the student variable as a new Student instead of just letting the if/else statement initialize it.